# Why is E(Y|X) a RANDOM VARIABLE?

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

Is E(Y|X) a RANDOM VARIABLE ?

X is a random variable so I suppose E(Y|X) is also a random variable since its value depends on X ?

Am I right ? If yes, Then what distribution does it follow and what is its mean and variance ?

Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the question is not solved by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $E(Y|X)$ is a random variable, because its value is a function of the value that $X$ takes. Specifics of its distribution will depend on what $X$ and $Y$ are, and particularly the relationship between them.

Comment: But E(E(Y|X))=E(Y), always, and var(E(Y|X))≤var(Y), always.

Comment: Thank you very much. So E[X|Y] is a random variable but $E[X|Y=y]$ is a constant please?

Comment: That's right - $E(X|Y = y)$ is calculated by fixing a value of $Y$, and finding the expectation of $X$, so it's a single value.

Answer (score 0):

A random variable is a function from the sample space to the real numbers, i.e. $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.

For a random variable $Y$ and an event $\{X=x\}\subseteq\Omega$ we can compute the expected value
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=\sum_{y}y\mathbb{P}(Y=y|X=x).
$$
Then for every $\omega\in\Omega$,
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y|X)(\omega)=u(X(ω)),
$$
where $u(x)=E(Y∣X=x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ is also a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and is a random variable.

In other words, the random variable $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ assignes probability $\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ to the value $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Edit: This explanation is for discrete and one-dimensional random variables, but the same idea can be applied for continuous or general settings.

Comment: This "definition" works when X and Y are discrete but it collapses in the general case.

Comment: Yes, of course. You can change it to densities for continuous variables or with measures and integrals in general, but I thought this was sufficient to illustrate the point.

Comment: It is not, imho, the general case being not reducible to, and vastly more powerful than, the discrete one.

Comment: By the way, rereading this, you do not even explain how E(Y|X) is defined as a random variable on Omega.

Comment: Thanks, Did. I updated my answer. Seems like my attempt at a simplistic explanation got complicated and didn't achieve its purpose.

Comment: Re the revised version, note that one usually avoids the notation $E(Y\mid X=X(\omega))$, horribly prone to misinterpretations. One should prefer formulations such as $E(Y\mid X)(\omega)=u(X(\omega))$, where, for every $x$, $u(x)=E(Y\mid X=x)$.